# htmlString and document.createTextNode vs plain string in jquery

Tags: jquery

In the following webpage

http://api.jquery.com/after/

in the "Example: Inserts a DOM element after all paragraphs." section it includes the following code:

```
$( "p" ).after( document.createTextNode( "Hello" ) );
```

It seems that document.createTextNode() is actually unnecessary... it still works with a plain string...

e.g.

```
$('a').eq(0).after('TEST')
```

If you type that in the console (in Chrome and Firefox at least) it adds TEST onto the end of the StackExchange link in the top left.

On the .after() webpage it says it takes the following types:

> Type: htmlString or Element or Array or jQuery HTML string, DOM
>   element, array of elements, or jQuery object to insert after each
>   element in the set of matched elements.

http://api.jquery.com/Types/#htmlString

says:

```
// Appends <b>hello</b>:
$( "<b>hello</b>" ).appendTo( "body" );

//Appends <b>hello</b>:
$( "<b>hello</b>bye" ).appendTo( "body" );   //

// Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
bye<b>hello</b> $("bye<b>hello</b>" ).appendTo( "body" );
```

Things like this work though....

```
$('a').eq(0).after('bye<b>hello</b>')
```

Anyway I haven't ever seen a non-HTML string being used in functions like after() before... I've only used them in things like text(). So is it a bad idea to use it since other people don't seem to use it? On the other hand without document.createTextNode() the code is simpler.

Comment: It used a node because it was an example of giving DOM elements to the method. Yes, a string can be used as well, but that wouldn't be an appropriate example for that context.

Answer (score 0):

You're unlikely to need to use syntax like that when appending a literal string. But you might get a text node by referencing some existing DOM element. The documentation was just using this as an example to show that DOM elements can be used.